# Can monero-wallet-cli be run as a light wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, light-wallet

I've set up a Monero node on my server machine ("barrow.home", 10.8.0.1 on my VPN), which is not entrusted with any private keys.

```
/opt/monero/monero-v0.11.0.0/monerod --non-interactive \
  --config-file /srv/monero/monero.conf
```

monero.conf:

```
log-file=/srv/monero/monero.log
data-dir=/bulk/monero/data
rpc-bind-ip=10.8.0.1
confirm-external-bind=1
hide-my-port=1
no-igd=1
```

From the log file it seems to be working correctly and synced up to the latest block (1409151).

On my laptop, I'm trying to run a "light" CLI client, also v.0.11.0.0, using the server as the full node:

```
monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host barrow.home --trusted-daemon \
  --restore-deterministic-wallet --restore-height 1335000 \
  --generate-new-wallet=temp --password ""
```

I type in my seed for an account for which the first transaction was after block 1335000. Everything works... *eventually*. But it still takes hours for the client to sync with the server. And as far as I can tell, the `--restore-height` option makes no difference.

So my question is: is there any way to get a "light wallet" experience with a client that only runs occasionally and a server that doesn't hold private keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug: the restore height should have been taken into account. If you don't specify a restore height, it actually works (you get asked for one, which is used). This will be fixed.